# Issue with photos being responsive? ( Wordpress )

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

I am working on a website and I am having issues with responsiveness. This is the Divi Theme for WordPress.
I would appreciate any help regarding this issue of when I scale down the browser there is a space that appears between the two sections... I have tried and tried to resolve this but I'm simply struggling with getting it to respond.

How it should look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMabK.jpg

How it looks for smaller browsers:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETayP.jpg

The test zone:
http://ndhhs.mavendd.com/

Thank you so much to anyone who knows a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the image as a Background Image for the column.
2. On row under Design->Sizing enable the option "Equalize the column heights". (This will enable display flex).

However, this solution doesn't work on mobile, so on mobile add the image using the image module and hide it on desktop or just add some padding y.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. This is sort of helping, but when I change the image to a BG image for the section column, because there is no 'content' it just comes up like this: https://imgur.com/BS2XhVy

Comment: Nevermind my above comment, I figured out that you can add the background to the column without a "section" being in it. This worked out PERFECT. Thank you so much!